# How to run multiple classes in parallel in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, automation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="4" parallel="tests"  preserve-order="true">
    <test name="Login - firefox">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.logintests.LoginTest" />
            <class name="com.qa.logouttest.LogoutTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Login - chrome">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.logintests.LoginTest" />
            <class name="com.qa.logouttest.LogoutTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

1. Need to run multiple classes in parallel, if I run with only 1 browser with parallel = none then the code works fine.
2. But If I use parallel = tests and try to run, then for second class named as "LogoutTest", I am facing null pointer exception.
3. Can anyone suggest me how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As we want classes to be executed in parallel, we have to add `parallel="classes"` in the attribute of suite tag.

Replace `parallel="tests"` with `parallel="classes"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" thread-count="4" parallel="classes">
    <test name="Login - firefox">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.logintests.LoginTest" />
            <class name="com.qa.logouttest.LogoutTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>

    <test name="Login - chrome">
        <parameter name="browserName" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class name="com.qa.logintests.LoginTest" />
            <class name="com.qa.logouttest.LogoutTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**Note:** If one class is dependent to other for example, logout is dependent to login, then it obvious that it will throw null pointer exception. And it wouldn't be wise to run dependent things in parallel.

Comment: @AshishGoyal Try removing `preserve-order="true"`